# When does the tabular method for integration by parts not work?

Tags: calculus, integration

I recently read a formula regarding integration

$$\int{e}^{ax}\sin bx\,dx= \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}(a\sin x-b\cos bx)+c \;. $$

And also a few days ago I came across the DI method or the [Tabular method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Tabular_integration_by_parts). But when I am trying to derive this using the DI method I am not able to get the answer because the table never reaches zero.

Yes I know it can be easily derived through simple by parts but if someone could guide me about why it is not working with DE Method.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by Tabular/ DE method?

Comment: Is this what you meant by Tabular method?: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/tabular-integration#:~:text=Example%201-,Tabular%20Integration,two%20types%20of%20Tabular%20Integration

Comment: yes @Koro this is the method am talking about

Comment: @PeterForeman can you send me the link?

Comment: @JustTolerateMe See the second example on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Tabular_integration_by_parts) Wiki sub-section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabular method will work, in just the same way as the traditional by parts method works. The last row in the table is the integral still to be done. You will find that the third row in your table (the integral still to do) is a multiple of the original integral. If you call the original integral $I$ then you obtain  $$I= e^{ax}( -\frac{1}{b}cos(bx))+ ae^{ax}( -\frac{1}{b^2}sin(bx))-\frac{a^2}{b^2}I$$  and solve for $I$.

Answer (score 1):

$I=\int f(x)g(x) dx$. Suppose that  $f$ is differentiable and $g$ is integrable. 
Applying integration by parts:

> $I=f(x) \int g(x)dx-\int f'(x)(\int g(x)dx) dx=f(x)\int g(x)dx-[f'(x)\int (\int g(x) dx)dx-\int (f''(x) \int (\int g(x) dx)dx)dx$
>
> etc.

In general, if $I$ and $II$ are "well-behaved" functions, we can
write: 
 $\int (I)(II)dx=I \int (II)dx-\text{(1st derivative of I)}\text{(integration of II)}+\text {(2nd derivative of I)(integration of integration of II)}-...$

For this we require that some $n$th derivative of $I$ must be zero. For example: 
$\int x^3 \sin x dx=x^3 (-\cos x)-(3x^2)(-\sin x)+(6x)(\cos x)-(6)(\sin x)+(0)(-\cos x)$

Note that here $3$rd derivative of $x^3$ is zero, hence tabular method terminates.

**In your case, both $e^{ax}$ and $\sin (bx)$ are infinitely differentiable & integrable and their derivative never becomes identically zero. That's why Tabular method doesn't terminate.**

Comment: yeah that's what i wanted to know, if this method works for all or not thanks @Koro

Comment: @JustTolerateMe: No, it doesn't work for all because all functions don't have high derivatives identically zero unlike polynomial functions for which this method indeed can be employed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the tabulated integral $\int e^{kx} dx=\frac{e^{kx}}{k}$ as below
$$I=\int e^{ax} \sin bx dx= \Im \left( \int e^{(a+ib)x}~dx\right)= \Im \left( \frac{e^{(a+ib)x}}{a+ib} \right).$$
$$\implies I=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}[a\sin bx-b \cos bx]+C$$

Comment: I don't think that this is what OP meant by tabular method.